# AWS React + Rails Redis server websocket issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, actioncable

I have a React + Rails app and I'm trying to configure my web application to use ActionCable. I've been struggling for several days with getting my websocket connection to work.

The architecture works like this:

1. The user goes to https://myapp.com and it serves them the static react application from an S3 bucket
2. The user makes requests from the browser that are directed to https://loadbalancer.myapp.com which directs them to one of the running tasks (rails servers)

I created elasticache redis cluster using AWS easy create + demo with the default settings. It has the configuration endpoint `clustercfg.foo.amazonaws.com:6379`

in my config/cable.yml I added:

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://clustercfg.foo.amazonaws.com:6379/1
```

In my config/environments/production.rb I have it set to allow all http/https origins:

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = "/cable"
config.action_cable.url = "wss://loadbalancer.liverapcenter.com/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

In my react app I have

```
const actionCableEndpoint = 'wss://loadbalancer.liverapcenter.com/cable';
CableApp.cable = actionCable.createConsumer(actionCableEndpoint);
```

In my network tab, all my normal HTTPS requests to the sever work fine and when I try to open a socket connection, it looks like there are continuous connections being made to /cable over wss:// every n seconds (which I think is correct), but the socket connection doesn't work.

[image]

The only error message I see in the browser log is:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://loadbalancer.liverapcenter.com/cable' failed:`

My server logs show this error, which seem to imply it's related to CORS:

[image]

I have rack-cors installed and my config/initializers/cors.rb file is:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
    end
end
```

so it should be allowing all origins. This is also the same origin that hits my /graphql endpoint and fetches data from the database using http requests with no issue

In my config/environments/production.rb I added

config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

which per the rails docks should allow requests from any origin. This is what I see locally when I check my ActionCable config:

[image]

In case anyone is interested, I have even more information about my AWS configuration and an example of the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6Z84l8BwxA